How create chevron arrows connected with 2 divs
I need create 2 divs connected with 2 divs. I have some issues when trying to reduce space between divs. The issue comes when I create pseudo elements ::after .left block and ::before .right block each block when I try to reduce space as in my 'What I need' picture below , one pseudo element overlays another one.


 .banner {
    height: 120px;
    display: flex;
  }
  
   .left,
    .right {
      // margin-left: 30px;
      background-color: #767676;
      padding: 30px 40px;
      color: #fff;
      position: relative;
    }

    .left {
      margin-left: 0;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-end-start-radius: 20px;
    }
    
     .left::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 60px solid transparent;
        border-left: 40px solid #767676;
        border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

        // margin: -30px 90px 0 40px;
        margin: -30px 0 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #fff;
      }

    .right {
      border-end-end-radius: 20px;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    }
    
       .right::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        left: 0;
        border-top: 60px solid transparent;
        border-left: 40px solid white;
        border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
        margin: -30px 0 0;
      }
<div class="banner flex">
<div class="left">Application Received</div>
<div class="right">Language Exam</div>
</div>



what I need

what I have when I try to reduce space between divs

Here is link to code

The example you have provided works fine. How are you trying to reduce the space between divs?

https://css-shape.com/breadcrumb/ (and https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-breadcrumb-navigation-with-css)

@dashingdove you can see in my screenshot (gray background) that one block is overlaying another one. Not like in my screenshot what I need

@Sunstrike527 Instead of setting the background color of .left::after, move that part so that it sticks out of the right side of the .left box. Then add a gap to the .banner for the desired spacing. I wanted to post a proper answer but alas the question was closed...
